# ¿Como puedo copiar el contenido del textarea correspondiente?

Tags: javascript

El usuario, a despúes de rellenar varios formularios, cuando le da a submit, genera un div. Puede rellenar muchos formularios y crear muchos divs distintos. Los divs se van añadiendo a un container. Cada div está compuesto por la misma estructura, mismas clases, id's, nombres... y se muestran varios elementos. Uno de ellos es el textarea, y cada textarea contiene un texto distinto.

```js
// Constructor UI

class UI {
 copyMetaTags(element){
        if (element.name === 'copiar') {
            document.getElementById("textarea").select()
            document.execCommand("copy");
        }
    }
  deleteSnipet(element) {
          if (element.name === 'delete') {
              element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
              this.showMessage('Borrado', 'success');
        }
  }
}    


// Eventos DOM

document.getElementById('simulador')
    .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const ui = new UI();
        ui.copyMetaTags(e.target);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    
document.getElementById('simulador')
    .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const ui = new UI();
        ui.deleteSnipet(e.target);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.container-btn-mtg{
 text-align: center;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="simulador" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
 <div>
  <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</textarea>
  <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar" name="copiar">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Borrar</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <textarea class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</textarea>
  <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar" name="copiar">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Borrar</a>
  </div>
 </div>

<div>
  <textarea class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</textarea>
 <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar" name="copiar">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Borrar</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando se dé el evento click en el botón de copiar dentro de cada uno de los textarea se seleccione y copie el textarea en cuestión. ¿Igual la solución es seleccionar los textarea con previousSibling? (No consigo localizarlo)

Para añadir a la interfaz del usuario la opción de borrar únicamente el div al que pertenece el botón clickado lo he hecho de la siguiente manera, y funciona perfecto:

```
deleteSnipet(element) {
        if (element.name === 'delete') {
            element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            this.showMessage('Borrado', 'success');
        }}
```

Me interesaría hacer lo mismo para copiar el contenido del textarea. 
No se si se puede seleccionar el contenido del textarea mediante

```
element.parentElement.previousSibling.select();
```

Comment: debes crear un id de textarea para cada uno , asi no tendras el problema

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada hay errores en tu HTML, no es recomendable poner un mismo ID a diferente etiqueta ya que un ID es un **identificador único**, entonces estabas agregando el ID `copiar` a todos los inputs tipo button, digo no es recomendable porque si lo seleccionas con `querySelectorAll()` te va a traer un array de las etiquetas que encuentre, por eso cambie `id` tanto en los button's como en los textarea ya que sólo le pusiste un id al primer textarea, además de que siempre validas que el elemento que oprimiste su `name` sea **copiar** seleccione la etiqueta `textarea` con el `id="textarea"`, si observas selecciono los botones con `querySelectorAll()` y los selecciono por su clase `.btn-success` para más información entra [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), después tengo que recorrer ese arreglo, uso forEach info [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), después le agrego un `listener` pero a cada botón, y con el método `this.name` selecciono el nombre de mi botón que estoy oprimiendo, se pasa como parámetro a tu constructor, yo quite el `if` y puse un `switch` pero lo puedes hacer como más te acomodes y bueno se valida que botón oprimiste y que `textarea` debe seleccionar y copiar, espero me hayas entendido, cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
// Constructor UI

class UI {
 copyTextarea(element){
        /*if (element === 'copiar1') {
            document.getElementById("textarea1").select()
            document.execCommand("copy");
        }*/
        
        switch(element){
        case'copiar1':
        document.getElementById("textarea1").select()
            document.execCommand("copy");
        
        break;
         case'copiar2':
        document.getElementById("textarea2").select()
            document.execCommand("copy");
        
        break;
         case'copiar3':
        document.getElementById("textarea3").select()
            document.execCommand("copy");
        
        break;
        
        
        }
    }
}

// Eventos DOM

/*document.getElementById('simulador')
    .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const ui = new UI();
        ui.copyTextarea(e.target);
        e.preventDefault();
    });*/
    
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success');
    
    btns.forEach(function(btn){
    
   //console.log(btn);
    
     btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    
    const ui = new UI();
        ui.copyTextarea(this.name);
  
    
    });
    
    })
```

```css
.container-btn-mtg{
 text-align: center;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="simulador" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
 <div>
  <textarea id="textarea1" class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Este es el contenido que se selecciona del primer textarea.</textarea>
  <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar1" name="copiar1">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete-ejemplo">Borrar</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <textarea id="textarea2" class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Este es el contenido que se selecciona del segundo textarea.</textarea>
  <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar2" name="copiar2">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete-ejemplo">Borrar</a>
  </div>
 </div>

<div>
  <textarea id="textarea3" class="form-control response" readonly="" rows="7">Este es el contenido que se selecciona del tercero textarea.</textarea>
 <div class="container container-btn-mtg">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="copiar3" name="copiar3">Copiar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete-ejemplo">Borrar</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @Vick. Entiendo perfectamente lo que me comentas. Ya he borrado mi "respuesta" anterior y he editado la pregunta.